# How to do an API call with Future and Uri.Https constructor in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Trying to build a Recipe App using Spoonacular API. Tried googling for answers but it seems like there was a change in uri.https format and all of the search results are from last year and older. I can't figure out the correct format for this? This is my first time calling APIs in flutter and I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the tutorial: https://youtu.be/l3CIMZSAaIk
And here's the source code: https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_recipe_app

This link shows how to generate a meal plan:
https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Generate-Meal-Plan

Here's how I'm trying to call it in URL form:
[https://api.spoonacular.com/mealplanner/generate?apiKey=[CHANGE_THIS_TO_APIKEY]&timeFrame=day&1700&vegan](https://api.spoonacular.com/mealplanner/generate?apiKey=%5BCHANGE_THIS_TO_APIKEY%5D&timeFrame=day&1700&vegan)

This works perfectly in the browser and I need to convert it to flutter code:

```
class APIservice {
  APIservice._instantiate();

  static final APIservice instance = APIservice._instantiate();

  final String _baseUrl = 'api.spoonacular.com';
  static const String API_KEY = '[APIKEY HERE]';

  //Generate Meal Plan
  Future<MealPlan> generateMealPlan({int targetCalories, String diet}) async {
    if (diet == 'None') diet = '';
    Map<String, String> parameters = {
      'apiKey': API_KEY,
      'timeFrame': 'day',
      'targetCalories': targetCalories.toString(),
      'diet': diet,
    };
    Uri uri = Uri.https(
      _baseUrl,
      '/mealplanner/generate',
      parameters,
    );
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    };

    try {
      var response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      MealPlan mealPlan = MealPlan.fromMap(data);
      return mealPlan;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err.toString();
    }
  }
```

When I run the app I get the error below:

**E/flutter ( 6458): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 6458): #0      APIservice.generateMealPlan [39;49m
E/flutter ( 6458):**

It looks like it's having problems piecing the parameters to turn into URL. I'm not sure if I wrote the MAP parameters and URI format correctly though.

Comment: Why do you have a `?` before the `apiKey` in the `parameters` map ?

Comment: @void Hey, thanks for asking. I've already removed it. It's a typo I made earlier but I corrected that now in my code. I'll edit it in here as well.

Comment: What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: @void Sorry for not being clear earlier. I edited my post hope I explained my issue clearly this time. Thanks for looking into this though.

Comment: Be sure to remove the `diet` entry from the `parameters` map if it is `none`, might be the possible cause of the issue. Everything else looks good.

Comment: oh snap. I forgot to add the diet parameter. I edited the URL in my post again. it should have the type of diet in it. It's user-selected. The app will generate the meal plan based on the diet type of the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220549/discussion-between-void-and-michael-banawa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the `Meal` model. The `Meal` model you had was different from what the api was returning:

I fixed the `Meal` model, check the code below:

```
class Meal {
  int id;
  String imageType;
  String title;
  int readyInMinutes;
  int servings;
  String sourceUrl;

  Meal(
      {this.id,
      this.imageType,
      this.title,
      this.readyInMinutes,
      this.servings,
      this.sourceUrl});

  Meal.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    imageType = json['imageType'];
    title = json['title'];
    readyInMinutes = json['readyInMinutes'];
    servings = json['servings'];
    sourceUrl = json['sourceUrl'];
  }
}
```

For some reasons, looks like the api doesn't really provide adequate support for the respective images, some images link are broken.

The app result looks like below:

[image]

Comment: you my sir.... are AMAZING. Thank you for helping. I'll figure the formatting stuff out from here. Thank You!